# Smaller parskip than half for KOMA-Script?

Tags: indentation, koma-script, paragraphs, parskip

I am using the documentclass scrbook. To mark paragraphs I need both vertical spacing and indentation.

I know that KOMA-Script supports the option `parskip` or `halfparskip`, however, this disables the indentation. In order to get it back I declared `\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}` in the preamble.

Since I am using both vertical spacing and indentation, I would like to have even smaller spacing than halfparskip. Is it possible to get an even smaller parskip than half in KOMA-Script?

Comment: You could use something like `\setparsizes{1em}{0.25\baselineskip plus .25\baselineskip}{1em plus 1fil}`. The first value is parindent, the second parskip, the third parfilskip. "half" uses 0.5 in the second argument.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Please make this an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use something like

```
\setparsizes{1em}{0.25\baselineskip plus .25\baselineskip}{1em plus 1fil}.
```

The first value is parindent, the second parskip, the third parfilskip. "half" uses 0.5 in the second argument.