# set \parskip but not for headings

Tags: sectioning, paragraphs

I want to define the vertical space  that is inserted between text paragraphs when there is an empty line in the code. 
If I use

```
\setparsizes{0pt}{1.0\baselineskip}{0pt plus 1fil}
```

or

```
\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

then it affects also the vertical space between the headings and other.

Is there an easy solution where I do not have to use something like `\mypar` 
with`\newcommand{\mypar}{\par\bigskip}`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

%% Method by KOMA-Script
%\setparsizes{0pt}{1.0\baselineskip}{0pt plus 1fil}

%% Other Method
\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{}
==========================================
    \section{TestSection Large Space}
    \subsection{TestSubsection Large Space}
    \subsubsection{TestSubSubsection Large Space}
Here we have big vertical space between headings because parskip

is inserted. I just want a parskip between text paragraphs.

==========================================

\newcommand{\mypar}{\par\bigskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \section{TestSection space I want}
    \subsection{TestSubSection space I want}
    \subsubsection{TestSubSubsection space I want}
Here I have the space between the headings that I want. And the space between text-paragraphs that I want. 
\mypar
I wonder if there is an easy way to achieve this. 
I would like to keep using an empty line as par bigskip instead newcommand a new command to achieve that. 
\end{document}
```

[image: set Vertical Space between headings ans text paragraphs]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not set `\parskip` manually. The default way for KOMA-Script classes is using the `parskip` option with a value like `half`, `full`, `full-` etc. See the documentation for more details - and see the comment of [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) below.

To set the skip before or after a heading level use

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=<length or glue>,
  afterskip=<length or glue>
]{<heading level name>}
```

But the vertical space after a heading is at least `\parskip` even if you use the smallest positive value `afterskip=1sp`. If there is a negative value for `afterskip` a horizontal skip instead a vertical skip is used. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292202/43317.

If you really want to remove the the space inserted by `\parskip` at the end of the heading there is a hack

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\sectionlinesformat}{\vspace*{-\parskip}}{}{}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full-]{scrreprt}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=3.3\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.725\baselineskip plus .115\baselineskip minus .192\baselineskip
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-2ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=-1.75ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex
]{subsection,subsubsection}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\sectionlinesformat}{\vspace*{-\parskip}}{}{}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{TestSection Large Space}
\subsection{TestSubsection Large Space}
\subsubsection{TestSubSubsection Large Space}
\Blindtext[2]
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: The easiest answer is “don't set `\parskip` either manually or with KoMa-Script methods.” `;-)`

Comment: Thank you for the hack.  That only was the answer to my question.But your long answer might help others. Thats great.

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the `parskip` below `half` that your described solution still works? I only found https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161254/smaller-parskip-than-half-for-koma-script which seems like a manual setting which isn't recommend.

Comment: @mhellmeier `\setparsizes` is descriped in the KOMA-Script documentation. You can use it, if you need a smaller `parskip` than `half`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just modify `\parskip` within a group to restrict  there effect inside this group

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

%% Method by KOMA-Script
%\setparsizes{0pt}{1.0\baselineskip}{0pt plus 1fil}

%% Other Method
\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

{\parskip=0pt 
    \chapter{}
==========================================
    \section{TestSection Large Space}
    \subsection{TestSubsection Large Space}
    \subsubsection{TestSubSubsection Large Space}
}

Here we have big vertical space between headings because parskip

is inserted. I just want a parskip between text paragraphs.

==========================================

{\parskip=0pt
    \section{TestSection space I want}
    \subsection{TestSubSection space I want}
    \subsubsection{TestSubSubsection space I want}
}    
Here I have the space between the headings that I want. And the space between text-paragraphs that I want. 

I wonder if there is an easy way to achieve this. 
I would like to keep using an empty line as par bigskip instead newcommand a new command to achieve that. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works as a quick fix:

```
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
```

Comment: Nice pragmetic solution which causes some side effects: It will reduce the cell spacing in your table cells as an example.