# KOMA-Script have parskip=full- but no spacing between section title and content

Tags: spacing, sectioning, koma-script

When using KOMA-Script, one has `\RedeclareSectionCommand` available to adjust the spacing before/after section titles, as [described in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223508/10478).

I want the content of the section to appear on the immediate next line under the section title, without any extra vertical space. The following mwe shows the content as I want it:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\begin{document}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=1pt]{section} %the magic happens here

\section{Foo}
    This is some text to show off
\section{Bar}
    This is some text to show off
\section{Baz}
    This is some text to show off  
\end{document}
```

In my actual document however, I use `parskip=full-` as argument to `\documentclass`. This has the effect, that there will be an empty line between the section title and the section content, which I don't want. The mwe also shows this behaviour. Every allowed value for parskip with starts with `full` or `half` shows this behaviour.

I think this is the normal and expected behaviour, as the german documentation explicitly states that the whitespace *preceedes* the paragraph.

Because time is an issue right now, I hacked it by putting `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` after every `\section{}`, but this is of course unacceptable for long term use.

How do I get the behaviour of `parskip=full-` and `\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=1pt]{section}`, with the exception that I don't want any vertical space between the section title and the corresponsing content?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300541/43317 and if you can read German see also http://www.komascript.de/node/2039

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

It is still not recommanded but now possible without patching a command because 
**KOMA-Script version 3.26** introduces two new keys to `\RedeclareSectionCommand` and `\RedeclareSectionCommands`: `runin` and `afterindent`. Possible values for both keys are `bysign`, `true` and `false`. For more information see the KOMA-Script documentation or eg [Adjusting spacing around section/subsection titles with koma-script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223524/43317).

Using the new key `runin` with value `false`¹ it is possible to remove the `\parskip` between the heading and the following text by `afterskip=-\parskip`.

Example:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full-]{scrartcl}[2015/10/03]
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  runin=false,
  afterskip=-\parskip
]{section}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
    This is some text to show off

    This is some text to show off
\section{Bar}
    This is some text to show off

    This is some text to show off
\section{Baz}
    This is some text to show off

    This is some text to show off
\end{document}
```

The (ugly) result is the same as in the original answer below.

¹ Default setting is `runin=bysign` which results in the same behavior as in the original answer.

---

**Original answer**

It is not recommended - see tex.stackexchange.com/a/300541/43317 and komascript.de/node/2039 (German) - but possible with KOMA-Script version 3.19 or newer:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full-]{scrartcl}[2015/10/03]
\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=1sp]{section} %the magic happens here
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\sectionlinesformat{\vspace*{-\parskip}}{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
    This is some text to show off

    This is some text to show off
\section{Bar}
    This is some text to show off

    This is some text to show off
\section{Baz}
    This is some text to show off

    This is some text to show off
\end{document}
```

As you can see the result looks weird:

[image]