# Negate the effect of parskip on headings

Tags: sectioning, parskip

[image: image1] [image: image2]

The tex file to produce the image on the right is given below. The image on the left is produced by uncommenting `\usepackage{parskip}`. My aim is to set distance between headings and also distance between heading and text with `\titlesec`. But `parskip` package which is needed for adding space between paragraphs, undesirably adds space after headings. I would like to **negate the effect of `parskip` on headings** and easily adjust  distances for headings with `titlesec`.

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300528/set-parskip-but-not-for-headings) is for KOMA-Script classes, so I guess the solution there would not work for me.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\centering\fontsize{16}{1}\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\fontsize{16}{1}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{INTRODUCTION}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`\fontsize{16}{1}` is wrong, the second argument is the distance of baselines and should always be larger then the fontsize.

Beside this you can reset \parskip and \baselinestretch in the heading:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\centering\parskip=0pt \renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}%
     \fontsize{16}{18}\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\fontsize{16}{18}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{INTRODUCTION}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would like to set the distance between INTRODUCTION and text as 24pt. Even though I set the distance as 0pt with `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}`, there is still some distance between them. Also, why you set the second argument of `\fontsize{16}{18}` as 18 but not 16?

Comment: I used 18 instead of 16 as normally the distance should be larger than the fontsize (the values for normalsize are e.g 12/14.5). If you have a new question ask a new question, don't ping only me personally in a comment.