# parindent with KOMAscript

Tags: parindent

I have decided to use KOMA for my new project. I'm writing in Spanish so I have to indent every first paragraph line, but I also want to include a paragraph separation of 1/2 line.

If I set KOMAoption to `parksip=false` I get the indentation but not the space between paragraphs. If I set `parskip=half`, the otherway around.

The only option I found is setting `parskip=half` and after `begin{document}` include `\setlength{\parindent}{1em}`. But then, I don't know if someother spacing settings in KOMA will be changed.

Is there any option I haven't found in KOMA that makes it possible to do it in a more elegant way.

Any comment is more than welcome.

Comment: I don't think any of the predefined `parskip` values does that. You probably have to use `\setparsizes`: `\setparsizes{1em}{.5\baselineskip plus .5\baselineskip}{0pt plus 1fil}`.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161254/35864

Comment: Thanks a lot to you both. It seems to work. If you consider I should delete the post, no problem at all, as it is quite similar question.